# Swift: CBCentralManager cannot find any devices

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am attempting to follow the tutorial on this [page](http://www.kevinhoyt.com/2016/05/20/the-12-steps-of-bluetooth-swift/), towards listing and communicating with BLE devices.

Unlike the author, I am not interested in making a GUI application, and would rather keep it console based.

I have made two files to test bluetooth communication, main.swift and BluetoothWorker.swift.

The main class looks as follows:

```
import Foundation

var worker = BluetoothWorker();
worker.findStretchSensor();

while worker.foundAddresses.isEmpty {
    print("### no devices found, sleeping");
    sleep(5);
    print("### done sleeping");
}
```

Here is how my Bluetooth class looks like:

```
import Foundation

import CoreBluetooth;

class BluetoothWorker: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    var foundAddresses = [String]();
    var manager = CBCentralManager();
    var myPherif: CBPeripheral?;

    func findStretchSensor() {
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil);

        print("### we are in the find sensor");
        if (myPherif != nil) {
            print("### we are canceling");
            manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(myPherif!);
        }

        print("### we are scanning for devices");
        manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil);
    }


    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("### we are checking the state");
        if (central.state != CBCentralManagerState.poweredOn) {
            print("### bluetooth is not available");
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("we found a device");
        if (peripheral.name != nil) {
            let message: String = "found peripheral:: " + peripheral.name!;
            foundAddresses.append(peripheral.name!);
            print(message);
        }
    }
}
```

My console output looks as follows:

```
### we are in the find sensor
### we are scanning for devices
### no devices found, sleeping
### done sleeping
### no devices found, sleeping
### done sleeping
### no devices found, sleeping
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why any of the devices are not listed, ad why the delegated methods are not executing. If I download this example [library](https://github.com/StretchSense/MacOS-Library) ( that works very similar to one of my bluetooth devices ), my device is recognized. ( Note, this library is also GUI based )

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: `centralManagerDidUpdateState()` isn't called at all? You should scan only if the state is `powerdOn`.

Comment: @Larme Correct, centralManagerDidUpdateState is never executed. I can confirm this as print("### we are checking the state"); never shows in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I'm seeing here:

1. You're calling `worker.findStretchSensor()` too early.

You have to wait until `centralManagerDidUpdateState()` reports `central.state == CBCentralManagerState.poweredOn`, i.e:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    print("### we are checking the state");
    if (central.state == .poweredOn) {
        findStretchSensor()
    }
}
```

You're wrongly assuming that `central.state` is already powered when you create a `CBCentralManager`. That's not the case. It takes a while to receive the `.poweredOn` state.

2. Since you're running an application without GUI, the main queue might not be adequate for handling the Bluetooth events, i.e. there might be no event loop where the Bluetooth stack could dispatch the events to. Probably that's why you're not getting any call to `centralManagerDidUpdateState()`.

Have you tried creating passing a queue for the central manager? I.e.:

```
queue = ...
manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: queue)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comments, centralManagerDidUpdateState() never executes. You are probably correct in that I might be calling a method too early, but regardless, it should not take more than several minutes to run. If I use a GUI based approach to this, everything goes as expected ( i.e I can see the device and can assure you it supports BLE )

Comment: Maybe your app's main queue is not adequate for handling Bluetooth events, have you tried using a custom queue? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sure enough, I added a DispatchQueue, and everything went as expected. I appreciate the clever thought.